# angular templateUrl disturbs link orders in dynamic compiling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are three angular directives: `trans`, `foo`, `bar`.

`trans` has an attribute of `{transclude: true}`.

`foo` has a template of `<bar></bar>`.

`bar` has a template of `<p>foobar!</p>`.

Think about creating a DOM like this dynamically using `$compile`:

```
<trans>
  <foo></foo>
</trans>
```

The expected link order is: `bar` -> `foo` -> `trans`.

When I create the directives with `template` attributes, it works well. But when I use `templateUrl`, the link order becomes: `foo` -> `trans` -> `bar`.

It seems that `templateUrl` causes an asynchronous compilation for `bar`. Is this a bug of Angular?

Is there any way to make it work without changing all `templateUrl`s into `template`s? Thanks.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gera2ld/n5y1aua3/3/) is the JsFiddle. (See console for the link orders.)

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an issue (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13616) and they say this is by design.